# In JQuery, why does $(this) == $(this) return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have run the following lines in my console (once a jquery script has been loaded), and received the following results:

```
$(this)
> [Window]
$(this) != $(this)
> true
$(this) == $(this)
> false
$(this) === $(this)
> false
```

And I don't know what steps to take to figure out what is going on. My guess is that there is some object that holds a time based value which is changing, but I wonder if it's something different. I will try to compare the values in the meantime, but I was hoping someone might understand what is going on here.

Edited to address the point that I was unaware of the underlying implementation of $(arg). I did not know that it returned a new reference object. Therefore, I don't believe this is a duplicate of "How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: _"I will try to compare the values in the meantime"_ What are you trying to determine?

Comment: @guest271314 Comparing to see if all properties are equal in value. I see now that javascript equals evaluates based on equality alone AND that $(this) returns a new reference each time it is called.

Therefore, baao, I don't think this is a duplicate. I was unaware that $(this) returned a new reference object to "this" each time, and that is not addressed in your linked question.

Comment: The previous downvote seemed unfair.  It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `$()` returns an instance of jQuery. So, you create one instance with `this`, and another instance of `this`, you have two separate instances. Even though they share the same reference to `this`, the instances are not the same, and those are what is being compared.

---

It might help to have a visual example, and might make things a little more clear. jQuery operates like a class. So let's use an **very simple example** where for example's sake, the function `$()` doesn't exist:

```
class jQuery {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}

var obj1 = new jQuery(this);
var obj2 = new jQuery(this);

console.log(obj1 === obj2); // false
```

Both of those are using the exact same argument (`this`) to create a new "jQuery" object. But, once again, obj1 is a completely different instance than obj2. They both have their own unique place in memory.

Comment: +1 - Furthermore, if you want to compare the values, use `this === this`. To clarify, when you wrap it with `$()`, an instance of a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) is returned (you might want to clarify that in your answer).

Comment: Marked as the answer because it addresses the root of the question, which is essentially "what does $(...) return (or do under the hood)?".

Comment: @NicholasFolk, awesome. I also went ahead and added a more visible example of how that works due to JoshCrozier's comment.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, thank you for the suggestion to add clarification!